# How to populate array lists in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an assignment to read a file of student records, then calculate and display the final grade for each course. As an old procedural programmer, I'm having a hard time with figuring out the "proper" (e.g., most OO) program flow, given the UML from which we're supposed to start. A big problem is that this is my first time implementing Array Lists, and I'm still a little fuzzy on practical examples, even after perusing the Java Tutorials and a bunch of online samples. I think the end-of-semester brain fuzz is preventing me from applying those examples to this assignment.

Here's where I am so far:

My main method consists of

```
FinalStudentGrade finalGradeReport = new FinalStudentGrade();
finalGradeReport.MainMethod();
```

which calls `Students.PopulateStudents(@"grades.txt")` to display the grade report. `PopulateStudents()` reads the data file, creating a student object through the constructor, and based on the following data member:

```
string nameFirst;
string nameLast;
string studentID;
ArrayList Earned; 
ArrayList Possible; 
float average;
string letterGrade;
```

The `PopulateStudents` method reads the file, creates a Student object for each line in the file, including a calculated average and letter grade. Each of these students then need to be added to `List<Student> theStudentList;`

```
class Students
{
    List<Student> theStudentList;
    public bool PopulateStudents(string @sourceData)   
    {
        String sourcePath = sourceData;
        theStudentList = new List<Student>();
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(sourcePath);
            while (inputReader != null)
            {
                String inputLine = inputReader.ReadLine();
                char delim = ',';   
                String[] inputValues = inputLine.Split(delim);
```

....  and I'm Stuck ....

I was about to define `nameFirst = inputValues[1];`, `nameLast = inputValues[2];`, `studentID = inputValues[0];` etc., but then I realized that I'm not using the constructor to create the Student object.

Do need to create `Student.nameFirst=...`,  then populate `theStudentList` with those objects?  Or can I just define `theStudentList[recordCounter].nameFirst` (defining a `recordCounter` first, of course) because `theStudentList` is being instatiated as `List<Student>();`? What's the best way to proceed with that, and am I visualizing the program flow between classes in a good way?

Comment: I don't see any code that creates `Student` objects to add to `theStudentList`.  @DStanley's answer is what you need - as part of your loop.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't see a constructor defined, so I'm assuming you didn't define one that takes paramters.  If that's the case, you can either construct the object first, then set the properties:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.nameFirst = inputValues[1];
s.nameLast = inputValues[2];
s.studentID = inputValues[0];
```

or use initialization syntax

```
Student s = new Student() {
    nameFirst = inputValues[1]
    nameLast = inputValues[2]
    studentID = inputValues[0]
    };
```

If you *did* define a constriuctor (say one that takes the three properties you mentioned), then just use the constructor:

```
Student s = new Student(inputValues[1], inputValues[2], inputValues[0]);
```

then just add the created student:

```
theStudentList.Add(s);
```

Comment: +1 for initialization syntax.  OP just needs to make sure he creates a default constructor.

Comment: No he doesn't - a parameterless constructor will be available by default unless a different constructor is defined.  To be fair I added an option if a constructor _is_ defined.

Comment: I was assuming he already created a constructor he mentioned a constructor within the original post.  I was under the impression if you already have a constructor defined for your class, then you need to create a default one to use object initialization syntax.

Comment: OK...that all makes sense then. I do have a constructor already defined. I assume I instantiate the `new Student()` just INSIDE my `while (inputReader != null)` loop, and `theStudentList.Add(s)` just before the closing brace of the `while`? Does that make sense for progtram flow?

Comment: I'm a little confused because `List<Student> theStudenList` is inside the class but outside the `PopulateStudents` method, and instantiating a new instance of the list in inside the method, but outside the loop. I'm not quite sure why that is...but that's the code we were given to start with.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Not only it makes sense, but it's the most common way I've seen.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Being `List<Student> theStudenList' in the class but outside ' PopulateStudents' method means any other method can access it. And the list instance must be defined outside the loop: other wise there woulde be one different definition in each iteration. This way all the iterations use the same instance.

Comment: @dwwilson66 - `theStudentList` is defined as a _field_ member of the class, so you can reference it within any method of that class.  And you need to construct it outside the loop otherwise you'd be blowing it away with each iteration.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. Thanks. That makes sense. I finally feel like I'm comprehending this... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addendum to make it even simpler to read than D Stanley's answer:

```
theStudentList.Add(new Student {
    nameFirst = inputValues[1],
    nameLast = inputValues[2],
    studentID = inputValues[0]
});
```